# Objective-C if-statement entered on a wrong basis

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm an experienced programmer so this cryptic behaviour is a total mystery to me.

I have a simple `if`-statement that *should* only be entered when exactly two boolean variables are `false`. However, the `if`-statement is for some reason entered when only one of them is `false`.

My code looks like this:

```
BOOL connected = [self connected];

NSLog(@"Connected to the internet: %@", connected ? @"YES" : @"NO");

BOOL notConnectedMessageShown = ((FOLDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).notConnectedMessageShown;

NSLog(@"notConnectedMessageShown: %@", notConnectedMessageShown ? @"YES" : @"NO");

if (!connected && !notConnectedMessageShown);
{
    NSLog(@"Entering if statement");
}
```

And the `NSLog`prints the following:

```
"Connected to the internet: YES"
"notConnectedMessageShown: NO"
"Entering if statement"
```

I really do not understand. Since the first variable is `true`in the first place, the entire `if`-statement should be skipped according to my programming skills?

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end of your `if`

```
if (!connected && !notConnectedMessageShown);  <<--- this ; is wrong
```

This way the block for a "true" condition is simply empty, and your code always enters the block right after it.

It should be this:

```
if (!connected && !notConnectedMessageShown)  <<-- see here
{
   NSLog(@"Entering if statement");
}
```

Comment: Jesus Christ! No wonder it totally hadn't seen that. Thank you so much!